# Android ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback get swipe direction

Tags: android, swipe, itemtouchhelper

I have implemented swipe to dismiss into my recyclerview. It triggers 2 functions(editing of the record and deleting). If you swipe to the left, you edit it, if right, you delete it. I have such layout under the general part of the recyclerview item

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fe5722">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/edit_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_mode_edit_white_24dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/delete_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_delete_white_24dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

So, if you swipe to the left (delete item) the left icon (for editing) should be hidden till the end of swipe. However, I have no idea how to get the swipe direction in the ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback class. Please help.
RecyclerItemTouchHelper.java

```
public class RecyclerItemTouchHelper extends ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback {
private RecyclerItemTouchHelperListener listener;
private ImageView imageView;

public RecyclerItemTouchHelper(int dragDirs, int swipeDirs, RecyclerItemTouchHelperListener listener) {
    super(dragDirs, swipeDirs);
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
    return true;
}


@Override
public void onSelectedChanged(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int actionState) {
    if (viewHolder != null) {
        final View foregroundView = ((PasswordRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder) viewHolder).getLayout();
        getDefaultUIUtil().onSelected(foregroundView);
    }
}

@Override
public void onChildDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView,
                            RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY,
                            int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
    final View foregroundView = ((PasswordRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder) viewHolder).getLayout();
    getDefaultUIUtil().onDrawOver(c, recyclerView, foregroundView, dX, dY,
            actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
}

@Override
public void clearView(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
    final View foregroundView = ((PasswordRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder) viewHolder).getLayout();
    getDefaultUIUtil().clearView(foregroundView);
}

@Override
public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView,
                        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY,
                        int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
    ((PasswordRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder) viewHolder).setEditIconInvisible();
    final View foregroundView = ((PasswordRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder) viewHolder).getLayout();

    getDefaultUIUtil().onDraw(c, recyclerView, foregroundView, dX, dY,
            actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
}

@Override
public int getSwipeDirs(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {

    return super.getSwipeDirs(recyclerView, viewHolder);
}

@Override
public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
    listener.onSwiped(viewHolder, direction, viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
}

@Override
public int convertToAbsoluteDirection(int flags, int layoutDirection) {
    if(layoutDirection == ItemTouchHelper.LEFT){
        Log.d("myLogs", "Налево пошло");
    }
    return super.convertToAbsoluteDirection(flags, layoutDirection);
}

public interface RecyclerItemTouchHelperListener {
    void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction, int position);
}
```

}

Update: I have solved the issue, just updated the onChildDraw method:

```
@Override
public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView,
                        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY,
                        int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
    final View foregroundView = ((PasswordRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder) viewHolder).getLayout();
    if (actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE) {
        if (dX > 0) {
            ((PasswordRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder) viewHolder).getEditIcon().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ((PasswordRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder) viewHolder).getDeleteIcon().setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            ((PasswordRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder) viewHolder).getEditIcon().setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ((PasswordRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder) viewHolder).getDeleteIcon().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    getDefaultUIUtil().onDraw(c, recyclerView, foregroundView, dX, dY,
            actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
}
```

Comment: you have `onSwiped()` method, dont you?

Comment: @pskink yeah, but it is triggered only when item is completely swiped

Comment: and you want what?

Comment: I want to hide one of the icons when the swipe gesture is started

Comment: how do you know if its swipe or move? you would need to predict the future...

Comment: I have implemented only swipe without drag&drop. I just need to detect the swipe direction

Comment: I do not mind if it is a swipe or just a move. I need to hide one of the icons anyway

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ItemTouchHelper.Callback` has a public method [`onChildDraw()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper.Callback.html#onChildDraw(android.graphics.Canvas,%20android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView,%20android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder,%20float,%20float,%20int,%20boolean)) that will be called on every frame with a `dX` value. This value is the horizontal translation of the view due to the current swipe action being performed by the user.

You can use the value of `dX` (and whether it is now positive when it was previously zero or now negative when it was previously zero) to detect whether the user is swiping left-to-right or right-to-left.

```
private class MyItemTouchCallback extends ItemTouchHelper.Callback {

    private float previousDx = 0;

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        ...
        previousDx = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
        if (previousDx <= 0 && dX > 0) {
            // swiping from left to right
        }
        else if (previousDx >= 0 && dX < 0) {
            // swiping from right to left
        }

        ...

        previousDx = dX;
    }
}
```